# Календарь дежурств

Tags: ajax, php, база-данных, календарь

Доброго времени суток.

В Сети много мануалов по написанию ивент календарей, есть даже фреймворки, но я хочу написать календарь учета дежурств с админ панелью.

Отличия от событийных календарей:  
Нет событий, которые привязаны ко времени.
Есть прямая связка человек -> дата (день), нет привязки по времени.
И человек может иметь разный статус в этот день (например, болен, на работе, командирован), но статус только один (не может иметь 2 статуса одновременно: болен и командирован, например.)

Я не уверен, что моя БД mysql имеет верную архитектуру, если что, поправьте меня.

Таблица называется `<month>-<year>` (т.е. для каждого месяца формируется новая таблица, например, 11-2014 для текущего месяца).
[Скриншот в приложении](http://javascript.ru/forum/attachments/ajax/2444d1415545848-kalendar-ucheta-dezhurstv-sql-table-sample-jpg).

Поля таблицы:

```
ID   
Name   
1 <- Это поля дней месяца, в которых содержатся специфические ключи: Болен (S), Выходной(W), Дежурный (D) 
2 
3 
4 
.. 
31
```

Интерфейс юзера получаю легко, просто опрашивая нужную таблицу и формируя HTML таблицу с помощью PHP. [Скриншот в приложении](http://javascript.ru/forum/attachments/ajax/2442d1415545848-kalendar-ucheta-dezhurstv-admin-interface-selectable-grid-jpg).

Проблема с административным интерфейсом при форматировании данных о дежурных. 
Выборку необходимых полей для будущего присвоения статуса реализовал с помощью jquery UI библиотеки selectable. [Скриншот в приложении](http://javascript.ru/forum/attachments/ajax/2442d1415545848-kalendar-ucheta-dezhurstv-admin-interface-selectable-grid-jpg).

Вопрос в следующем: я не знаю, в каком виде и как сохранять данные в БД с помощью ajax.

1) Лучше по выбранным позициям исправить содержимое на нужный статус (проставить статус D во всех выбранных ячейках, например), а потом отправить ajax со всеми ячейками в базу данных.

2) Или сразу формировать запрос в БД по выбранным ячейкам и отправлять информацию в БД только по выбранным, затем перегружать страницу для формирования уже актуальных данных?

Ну и общий вопрос в том, как корректно отправить данные в БД с помощью ajax? (jquery изучаю второй день, сильно не пинайте, раньше с javascript не работал.)

Как мне корректно отправить данные в БД с каждой ячейки?

Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем на каждый месяц новая таблица?

Comment: нуу, хз.
Хранить месяц и год в отдельных полях одной таблицы?

По ощущениям, при большом объеме информации в БД быстрей обработчик будет находить таблицу из списка таблиц, чем перебирать все записи в одной таблице, сравнивая пару месяц-год

Comment: @SaLacoste вы начинаете писать решение проблемы с производительностью до ее появления. Эта штука называется шардинг, и, скорее всего, лучше ее будет реализовать внутри движка.

Comment: @Etki, ок, а по теме вопроса сможете помочь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Структура выбрана ужасная. И таблица должна быть одна, и поле для статуса тоже одно, и поле для даты тоже одно должно быть: они же во всех запросах всегда будут оба использоваться! Вам никогда не потребуются все дни года, и никогда не потребуются все дни января по всем годам. Для одного дня одного работника должна быть одна строка.

А какие данные аяксом отправлять, вообще никакой разницы нет. Хоть месяц, хоть только изменения, если нет совместного редактирования разными юзерами, то данные будут (при наличии связи/правильной работе сервера) и на клиенте, и на сервере идентичны, и рефрешить ничего не надо.

Кроме того, для общих выходных/праздничных дней делать отдельную таблицу с производственным календарем. При этом действительно для работников достаточно хранить только отличия, соединяя их по left join. Кстати бывают разные графики работы: пятидневка, шестидневка, сутки через трое, два через два и т.д.

Поэтому как минимум:

`Calendar`: (`day_of_year`, `status`), заполняется раз в год по [buh.ru](http://buh.ru/calendar/2014/) и нужному графику.
`Schedule`: (`person_id`, `day_of_year`, `status`) - отличия от производственного календаря. Плюс уникальный индекс по (`person_id`,`day_of_year`).

```
select c.day_of_year, ifnull(s.status, c.status) as status
from calendar c 
  left join schedule s on 
    c.day_of_year = s.day_of_year
    and c.person_id = $person_id
where 
  c.day_of_year between $beginofmonth and $endofmonth

insert into schedule (person_id, day_of_year, status) values 
  ($person_id, "2014-04-01", "w"),
  ($person_id, "2014-04-02", "s"),...
on duplicate key update status=values(status)
```

ЗЫ Пока скрины не посмотрел (пришлось зарегистрироваться!), думал, что все в порядке...

**Обновление**

Вы просили комментарии по структуре данных... Если вам только показывать данные, то структура не важна (хотя я и не сторонник такого подхода), можно хоть в файле их хранить, в сериализованном виде, например.

По ajax вам потребуется:

1. в обработчике получить данные которые надо отправить, вызвать `$.post('update.php', data)`; http://jsfiddle.net/w4rjnr4c/
2. в php файле получить массив data обработать его и записать в бд.

Обновлять страницу при этом не надо...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо большое за предметность изложения.
Моя потребность намного проще, так как я не делаю календарь рабочего времени или график работы, а это график дежурств на дому, для личного пользования нашего отдела. 
Таким образом нет связи с выходными, праздниками, а также календарем рабочего времени на год.

У человека есть просто 3 статуса (ключа) или пустое поле (когда он не болеет, не дежурит и не командирован).

Я не перебирал БД еще,  но собрал то, что есть на текущий момент http://jsfiddle.net/7m7qhrhh/1/

Я не знаю, как через ajax данные записать в БД целиком.

Comment: @SaLacoste, Обновил ответ

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо, что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Такое ощущение, что вы хотите от структуры своей базы какого-то наглядного соответствия реальному образу календаря. И почему обязательно каждому дню выставлять определенный статус? Пускай по умолчанию человек на работе - это же норма. Поэтому вам хранить остается только дату (День-Месяц-Год) и статус (идентификатор статуса из таблицы как вариант), и идентификатор работника из таблицы работников. Пустая база данных - это календарь без заметок - все дни, кроме выходных, люди были на работе. Вы лучше наглядность на интерфейс переложите, а не на структуру базы данных.